# The region of integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, spheres

So I was given this question $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 4$$ where $x≥0$, $y≤0$ and $z≤0$. I was told to sketch the $3D$ plot of the region $A$ and the projection region $R$ of $A$ in the $xy$-plane. How do I sketch this? I know its a sphere but how do I sketch it.

Comment: I think the answer is $\frac {4\pi (2)^3}{3*8}$ which is simply the 1/8 th of the volume of sphere described here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track.

The region $A$ isn't a complete sphere rather it is a octant of a sphere.

The region $R$ is a quarter circle.